# Contenteditable: prevent inner element from being deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, contenteditable

I have a simple contenteditable markup:

```
<div class="example" contenteditable="true">
     <div class="inside">Some content</div>
</div>
```

When I delete the "`Some content`", then `class="inside"` div also gets deleted. Is there a way to prevent the inside div from being removed when contents are deleted?

For example, this is the look I am trying to make once the contents are deleted.

```
<div class="example" contenteditable="true">
     <div class="inside"></div> <!-- The div is not deleted -->
</div>
```

I looked around but doesn't seem like there is a clear answer.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rzm156px/ it won't be deleted.

Comment: Hmm That's weird. on Chrome, everything gets deleted except the top div with `contenteditable` attr.

Comment: No. Something in your css breaking the code.

Comment: I see. I will double check it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have same problem with `<p>` inside a contenteditable div

Comment: @devhermluna I just ran your jsfiddle and if I keep backspacing "some content" then eventually the whole div deletes and you cannot type into it again

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```css
.inside, .example {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="example" contenteditable="true">
  <div class="inside">Some content</div>
</div>
```

Maybe there's a style that is inline-level element.

Since the width will be 0% when you remove the content. You cannot click it again or add any content.

So, my solution will be

```
.inside, .example {
  display: block;
}
```

You can specify width if you want. :)

```css
.inside, .example {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="example" contenteditable="true">
  <div class="inside">Some content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you inspect the element (in chrome), the inside div gets deleted in both cases.

Comment: @steveKim yeah. Now, I understand your question. Sorry, but is there particular reason why you dont want to use textbox?

Comment: Thank you for the help. I thought about using textarea, but I need to have some html markup inside of input field and textarea does not allow for html element inside. (For a better control of input data).

Comment: this is not an answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
const example = document.querySelector(".example")

example.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
 if (e.keyCode == 8 || e.keyCode == 46) { // delete and del keys
   if (example.children.length === 1) { // last inner element 
     if (example.children[0].innerText < 1) { // last element is empty
       e.preventDefault()
     }
   } 
 })
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help someone

```
function onpaste(e: ClipboardEvent) {
  e.preventDefault();

  const selection = window.getSelection();
  // Don't allow deleting nodes
  if (selection.anchorNode.isSameNode(selection.focusNode)) {
    // get text representation of clipboard
    const text = e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");

    // insert text manually, but without new line characters as can't support <br/>s yet
    document.execCommand("insertHTML", false, text.replace(/\n/g, ""));
  }
}

function onkeydownInEditable(e: KeyboardEvent) {
  if (e.key === "Enter") {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  if (e.key === "Backspace" || e.key === "Delete" || e.key === "Paste") {
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    // Don't allow deleting nodes
    if (!selection.anchorNode.isSameNode(selection.focusNode))
      e.preventDefault();
  }
}

 elementEditing.addEventListener("keydown", onkeydownInEditable);
 elementEditing.addEventListener("paste", onpaste);
```

Comment: not bad. this is a start. You can delete stuff by selecting a range and then press any key (for e.g space)

Comment: Hi, could you provide working demo? Thank you.

Comment: Also will add, while a tag may appear empty visually it probably has a <br> inside it so check for that with innerHTML. Also consider using onKeyUp as that is the end state

Answer (score -1):

You have to add `contenteditable="true"` to inside elements:

```
<div class="example">
     <div class="inside" contenteditable="true">Some content</div>
     <div class="inside">Some content</div> <!-- This one will not be deleted -->
     <div class="inside" contenteditable="true">Some content</div>
</div>
```